# What is the purpose of multiple setLayoutCounts of vulkan VkPipelineLayoutCreateInfo?

Tags: vulkan

I wondering why it's possible to specify multiple descriptors set layouts in VkPipelineLayoutCreateInfo because a single one already includes all of the bindings.

Answer (score 10):

A descriptor set layout describes the layout for a single descriptor set. But a pipeline can have *multiple* descriptor sets. This is what the `layout(set = #)` part of the qualifier in GLSL means: it specifies which set that this particular resource gets its descriptor from. The `set` is an index into the `VkPipelineLayoutCreateInfo::pSetLayouts` array. The `descriptor` is the index into that set's list of descriptors. The two of them combined identify the specific descriptor within the pipeline layout.

So your assumption that a single descriptor set "already includes all of the bindings" is incorrect.

As stated in the specification, the point of having multiple descriptor sets is to allow users to change one set of descriptors without changing another, and to allow pipelines to be partially layout compatible with one another.

For example, you might have per-scene information like the location of lights and the camera/projection matrices. But you might also have per-object information like the matrices. If all of that information is in the same descriptor set, then if you want different objects to have different per-object descriptor sets, they would also have to have different per-scene info in those same sets.

You can instead split them up into separate descriptor sets, with the less frequently changing information in set 0 (per-scene) and the more frequently changing data in set 1 (per-object). That way, you don't have to change *every* descriptor just to change your per-object data.

Also, you can change pipelines without having to restore the per-scene sets. For example, let's say you're switching from your non-skinned pipeline to your skinned pipeline. Well, obviously they have fundamentally different kinds of per-object data. But their per-scene data is *the same*. If you have these data in different descriptor sets, then you don't need another descriptor set for the per-scene data. You don't even need to bind a new set 0 when you change the program binding. Because set 0 is compatible with both programs, set 0's binding is valid in both.

The specification even has a notation specifically about this scenario:

> Place the least frequently changing descriptor sets near the start of the pipeline layout, and place the descriptor sets representing the most frequently changing resources near the end. When pipelines are switched, only the descriptor set bindings that have been invalidated will need to be updated and the remainder of the descriptor set bindings will remain in place.

Comment: If I want to update MVP and Texture, MVP is updated frequently and Texture is not updated.

Is the

`Layout (set = 0, binding = 0) uniform MVP;

Layout (set = 1, binding = 0) uniform sampler2D Texture;`

Better than the

`Layout (set = 0, binding = 0) uniform MVP;

Layout (set = 0, binding = 1) uniform sampler2D Texture;`

?